# Which of McCaffery's Dragonrider books am I missing?

Tags: story-identification, books, pern

I do not have all the *Dragons of Pern* books by Anne McCaffery or her children (I think they're her children). What I do have are these: The original three Dragonrider books, the Harper Hall of Pern series, and *All the Weyrs of Pern.* Here's my problem:

*The White Dragon* closes with our intrepid Pernese finding and beginning to excavate the ships used by the original colonists. *All the Weyrs of Pern* begins with the first-use of AIVAS. Time has passed between the two stories (Piemur is now married, etc.) On page 12 of the mass-market paperback we read:

> "Your beaded panels, Piemur," Jancis said, clutching at his sleeve with one hand and pointing excitedly with the other.
>
> You're right," Piemur said, "What are they, Aivas? We seem to have boxes and boxes of them, all different sorts."
>
> ...
>
> "Yes," Master Robinton said with surprise. "I couldn't think what they might be when I saw them, swathed in that thick film."

It's been years since I read the series and apparently I never thought to notice *that I've missed a book somewhere that describes the above events.* So I [hopped onto Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XM3RM3J) and tried to find what book(s) I was missing. The four books in the middle (*Moreta,* *Nerilka's Story,* *Dragonsdawn,* and *The Renegades of Pern*) all appear to be basically unrelated to this story line. (Should I buy them all? Probably, but I'd hate to do that and find that I didn't solve my problem!)

**Question:** Which book(s) in the *Dragons of Pern* series describes the events of finding the dumb terminals as shown in the excerpt from *All the Weyrs of Pern,* shown above?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You'll be wanting to pick up [*Renegades of Pern*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1314), which is the book where they dig up the old technological relics.

> 'Ad... min an... nex,' he read slowly, enunciating each syllable of the caption. 'For aivas. Aivas?' He looked enquiringly up at Jancis.
>
> 'I don't know what an aivas is either, but it must be important. See? They went to a lot of trouble to reinforce it. "Cer... a... mic tiles"-well, we know "tiles." Heat resistant, that's obvious, too. I don't understand what the figures mean, but "tolerance" would indicate they were determined to protect this aivas thing.' Jancis was excited.
>
> "Admin annex? We haven't excavated that one yet, have we? It's up near the edge of the lava flow. And what're so... lar pan... els?' he asked, tapping the long strips that were apparently attached to the roof of the aivas annex.
>
> 'Solar's an old word for sun. Panels, we know.'
>
> 'Sun panels? What would they do?'

The first description of a terminal from Piemur's point of view:

> The growing light made visible some of the details within the room: the worktables on either side of the door, and the two high stools neatly placed under them. On the wall opposite the door was **a large framed surface, tinted slightly green with little red letters blinking on and off in the lower left-hand side**. A chair, on a pedestal with five spokes in its base, stood in front of it and **the slanting workspace. It seemed unadorned until Piemur noticed the regular squares-lighter in color than the surrounding surface-set in ranks** and odd-looking protuberances in a series of rows to the right.